# Handlebars if/then when the condition is based on the text of an HTML element

Tags: jquery, html, handlebars.js

I an new to **Handlebars**, so forgive me if this is basic (but I can't find a simple explanation of this, so here I am).

I have an HTML element that has some value:

```
<div id="myElement">1234</div>
```

Later in my HTML I have a button element, and I need the caption of that button to change depending on what `myElement` has as its inner text.

I have tried the Handlebars `if/then` template code:

```
{{#if $('#myElement').text() == "1234" }}
{{/if}}
```

However my WebStorm JS IDE inspector is telling me that its expecting a closing tag `}}`, which I obviously have included.

So my question is: can Handlebars templates include jQuery like selectors for their condition expressions?